# Convert a String to JSON in scala.html file

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I am currently using a list of PropertyDTO s in my scala.html file to populate a view with Play2. The propertyDTO has a String attribute "value" which contains a JSON String. I want to convert this string to a JSON object in the scala.html file, and iterate through the JSON object collection. When trying the following,

val json = Json.parse(property.value),as[JsObject] within the scala code, it prints the expression. I would wish to know if my approach is correct, and if not , is there a suitable solution.

Code --> scala.html

```
    @(propertyList : List[PropertyDTO])

    @for(property <- propertyList){
        @if(property.isInputProperty){
            @if(property.propertyType=="BL"){         
                val json = Json.parse(property.value).as[JsObject]
            }     
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would not advise doing this in a template - the point of having templates, and not embedding HTML generation directly into your Scala code, is to separate the view logic from the application logic.  If you go embedding Scala code like this in your template, then what's the point in using a template?

Best practice is to prepare all your data for rendering before calling the template, and then pass it into the template, and keep the template as dumb as possible, just iterating and rendering values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to declare code to be interpreted as scala code by putting an `@` in front of it. The line

```scala
val json = Json.parse(property.value).as[JsObject]
```

gets interpreted as HTML as there is no @ sign in the line indicating scala code. What you can do is declare a whole block to contain scala code using `@{ ... }`.

For example you can store the result of your for comprehension in a variable for later use in the template:

```scala
@import play.api.libs.json._

@validPropertiesAsJson = @{
  for{
    property <- propertyList
    if property.isInputProperty
    if property.propertyType == "BL"
  } yield Json.parse(property.value).as[JsObject]
}
```

And later in the template use `@validPropertiesAsJson` to include the value.
More information can be found in the playframework documentation: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/ScalaTemplates

**Keep in mind to put as little logic into the template as possible.**